# Finding and replacing key and filename

Tags: regex, xml, file-rename

> a.xml

```
<component id="s1xmea" name="game.xml" path="/" exported="true"/>
<component id="p2jmhg" name="game_Info.xml" path="/views/label/"/>
<component id="ulerrkhlc" name="label_ante.xml" path="/views/label/"/>
```

> game_Info.xml

```
    <component id="n1_plny" name="title_cn" src="ulerrkhlc" fileName="views/label/label_ante.xml" xy="0,0" pivot="0.5,0.5"/>
```

I tried to find vscode extensions to help me to rename the file and updated the reference file at the same time. 
For example, if I change the name of the xml(from game_Info.xml to gameInfo.xml), the name in a.xml can also update from name="game_Info.xml" to name="gameInfo.xml" as well. 
Also, if I make changes on a.xml (from component id="ulerrkhlc" to component id="game01"), it can also updat the game_Info.xml(from src="ulerrkhlc" to src="game01").

Please any advised? I'd tried to use the extension - [Rename actions](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Gruntfuggly.rename-actions) and [Replace Rules](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=bhughes339.replacerules&ssr=false#overview)
still confused about about how it works. I had understood the Regex method, but still can't really get understand how to work on vscode.

Any help would be appreciated :)

Comment: To rename a file I would use the File.Rename() metod and to modify xml data use one of the Net XML libraries  like XML LINQ.

Comment: @jdweng May I have a further understanding of how it works? For example, should I write a JSON or using snippets, please?

Comment: XML is not JSON.  Use an XML Library.

Comment: @jdweng Thanks for reply to me. If I may, can you please tell me where I can find this XML Library? Many thanks.

Comment: What programming langues are you using.